# How to get the date time of client PC in asp.net C# server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET web application. My hosting server is in other country. Database is present there. 
Anyone can browse the site. Now I want to get the date time of client PC. I will store it in DB and will used in class file
Please give me the C# code.

Comment: Your question contains the answer to your own question, Accessing client-side information using server-side technology is not possible

Answer (score 1):

As code behind is running on server which is local to you but not in client side, You can not get time of client side from c#.

> You can, however, use JavaScript to get the current date/time from the
>   browser using  `Date()` and get data back to server using server-client communication.

Comment: and what if he change the machine time or different user around the world., that can effect your db..

Comment: var x = new Date();
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

Get offset in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use the server clock, because you can't trust the client clock. but you can use clients timezone information to estimate his datetime (client and server utc date time SHOULD be equal)

You can clients timezone onfo by javascript

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

send this information to the server and save it into the database beside the current utc time

Answer (score -3):

```
var serverDateTime =  DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: This is not the time from the client pc